# Website does not resolve in browser but traceroute is successful

Tags: dns, domain

I am trying to figure out an issue. My internet is working fine, but this one website is not resolving. It works via a proxy, traceroute works:

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  4.205 ms  0.568 ms  0.510 ms
 2  * * *
 3  67.59.255.13 (67.59.255.13)  10.583 ms  7.949 ms  7.557 ms
 4  67.59.255.61 (67.59.255.61)  10.256 ms  9.576 ms  13.083 ms
 5  64.15.8.126 (64.15.8.126)  9.943 ms  11.929 ms  11.452 ms
 6  64.15.0.217 (64.15.0.217)  14.655 ms  14.092 ms  13.771 ms
 7  64.15.0.118 (64.15.0.118)  33.201 ms  34.875 ms  36.544 ms
 8  xe-6-0-3.ar1.ord1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.111.169)  34.027 ms  34.957 ms  34.231 ms
 9  ae1-30g.cr1.ord1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.111.133)  82.683 ms  35.138 ms  37.592 ms
10  xe-3-0-0.cr2.iad1.us.nlayer.net (69.22.142.26)  41.657 ms  34.063 ms  34.519 ms
11  ae2-30g.ar2.iad1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.31.186)  35.780 ms  36.361 ms  33.968 ms
12  as33597.xe-3-0-7.ar2.iad1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.30.230)  35.086 ms
as33597.xe-3-0-7.ar2.iad1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.30.234)  38.031 ms
as33597.xe-3-0-7.ar2.iad1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.30.230)  36.833 ms
13  cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  32.595 ms
cr2.iad1.inforelay.net (66.231.176.10)  31.771 ms
cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  32.622 ms
14  cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  32.956 ms  33.625 ms !X  41.058 ms
15  * cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  35.312 ms !X *
16  * cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  32.814 ms !X *
17  cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246)  35.459 ms !X *  53.137 ms !X
```

Ping returns this:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
```

But what I can not figure out is why my browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera) can not resolve the domain. I am on a Wifi connection. What could be the problem?

BTW I am on a Mac (10.6.5)

Comment: What's the website? I see the tracert hops, but what is the site's domain that you're trying to reach?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think traceroute is working.  Traceroute's !X refers to "communication administratively prohibited" which means your traffic is being filtered.

Comment: @obfuscurity Would the filtering be from my ISP or would it be from a blacklist on the server?

Comment: Look at your traceroute.  The router at cr1.iad2.inforelay.net (66.231.176.246) is reporting back the message.

Comment: Seriously, what's the website addy?

Comment: Look at hop 9. 82ms is pretty high...look into bottlenecking around that hop.

Comment: Your problem description is kind of confusing. If you couldn't resolve the domain, how were you able to trace it? Your only problem description is that you can't "resolve the domain", which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem, where a number of websites would allow me to traceroute, but I could not access them or ping them (receiving the same icmp_seq timeout error).

The issue turned out to be my home router (Netgear DG834G) and a simple restart now and again fixes the problem. However I am none the wiser as to why this is happening, assuming its just a bug in the software, as it is usually after roughly the same uptime.

Have you tried restarting your router and trying again?

Comment: Router, Modem, Router again. Nothing

Comment: you may want to try to install DD-WRT software onto your router, it fixes some issues with me.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them if they are running mod_security - perhaps your IP is on a list of spammers.  This can happen by accident if you're testing code that sends email from your own system in an invalid way.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot resolve the domain, the problem is most likely with your DNS servers and not the site.